# FFMPEG to remote server: Live streaming with segments

Tags: ffmpeg

I have looked around and have found many good articles on how to use ffmpeg to segment live video for HLS streaming. However, I need to be able to use use an encoder from a remote location (that is receiving live video), and then somehow send these segmented files and the m3u8/ts files to a web server in a different location, in real time.

So:
REMOTE COMPUTER(camera->ffmpeg->segmenter) -> WEBSERVER(receives files -> users connect for "live" stream)

My question is: Has anyone seen something similar to this? Or is there a setting on ffmpeg/ffserver that will let me do this?

Comment: Is this your question, "How can I copy files from one computer to another?"

Answer (score 2):

ffmpeg does not have functionality to transfer the segmented files. Depending on your operating system, you would need to create a separate process (shell script, batch file, etc) that would migrate the ffmpeg-created segment files (as well as the m3u8 playlist) to their final destination on your webserver. Alternatively, if possible to run ffmpeg on the webserver, you could send the stream with ffmpeg using rtmp from the video source to ffmpeg on the webserver, where ffmpeg can write the segments and playlist out directly to the webserver file system.